# How can I prevent pycharm from displaying optional parameter hints?

Tags: python, pycharm, editor, display, hints

I get these big hints with optional arguments/parameters in pycharm:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeVt2.png

How can i disable them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html

Comment: No but I finally found the right option: Settings -> Editor -> Code Completion -> Show the parameter info popup in 1000 ms